# Mi código no almacena las imágenes que crea en la carpeta que puse como destino

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un código de reconocimiento facial con python y estoy buscando que el código cree y almacene imagenes de mi rostro con mi cámara web. El problema es que el código inicia y finaliza sin errores pero al momento en el que debería guardar las imagenes en la carpeta de destino, no las guarda.

A continuación dejo mi código:

```
import cv2 as cv
import os

modelo = 'FotosLucio'
ruta1 = 'C:/Users/usuario/Desktop/Programación/Python/Reconocimiento facial/Reconocimientofacial1'
rutacompleta = ruta1+'/'+modelo

if not os.path.exists(rutacompleta):
    os.makedirs(rutacompleta)


camara = cv.VideoCapture(0)

ruidos = cv.CascadeClassifier(cv.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')


id = 0

while True:
    respuesta, captura = camara.read()
    if respuesta == False:
        break
    grises = cv.cvtColor(captura, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    idcaptura = captura.copy()
    
    caras = ruidos.detectMultiScale(grises, 1.3, 5)

    for(x, y, e1, e2) in caras:
        cv.rectangle(captura, (x, y), (x+e1, y+e2), (0, 255 , 0), 2)
        rostrocapturado = idcaptura[y:y+e2,x:x+e1]
        rostrocapturado = cv.resize(rostrocapturado, (160, 160), interpolation=cv.INTER_CUBIC)
        cv.imwrite(rutacompleta+'/imagen_{}.jpg'.format(id), rostrocapturado)
        id = id + 1

    cv.imshow("Resultado rostro", captura)

    if id == 351:
        break

camara.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: no habías echo una pregunta similar?

Comment: Si, ese era un problema que me tiraba una advertencia y no corría el código. Ahora corre pero no guarda las imagenes en la carpeta

Comment: y no te da algún error?

Comment: No, ninguno. El único problema es que no almacena las imagenes en la carpeta que debería almacenarlas

Comment: Imagino que no tienes elementos en `caras`, por eso no entra en el ciclo, o bien `respuesta  == False`

Comment: Probé sacando ese if de ´´´respuesta == False ´´´ y seguía sin darme las imagenes. También antes de agregar al código lo de almacenar imágenes en una carpeta solo hice que me reconozca el rostro y funcionaba (marcaba mi rostro con un cuadro como dice en el código). Por eso es que no sé a que se debe el error

Comment: ¿Pero tienes un error? por lo que dices el código es como que no hiciera nada, es decir no se estuvieran detectando las caras